# How to trigger an airflow DAG to run immediately from UI (not schedule)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, airflow

I have an airflow DAG that looks like the following:

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator import SparkSubmitOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


args = {
    'owner': 'john',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 01)
}
dag = DAG('spark_example', default_args=args)

operator = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job',
    conn_id='spark_default',
    java_class='com.om.example.data',
    application='/home/ubuntu/my-jar-1.0.jar',
    total_executor_cores='1',
    executor_cores='1',
    executor_memory='1g',
    num_executors='2',
    name='airflow-spark-code',
    verbose=False,
    driver_memory='1g',
    application_args=["yarn", "172.168.1.23:9092", "kafka_group_1"],
    dag=dag,
)
```

Two questions:

> 1. How do I run this DAG immediately? I do not want to schedule it but not sure what params I need. The only way it works from commandLine is if i do: **airflow test spark_example spark_submit_job -1**

and...

> 2. From Airflow UI on 0.0.0.0:8080, How do I run this DAG **immediately**... when I click "play" it does nothing, but it says it is running and stays in that state forever

Comment: What's the status of the first task in the DAG run you trigger? If there is no status, can you click the task and go to "Task Instance Details", then see if it says anything under the first section "Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled"? That might give you a clue as to why nothing is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest only operator to run your DAG anytime you wants to.

```
latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id='latest_only', dag=dag)
```